# Android App to run continuously in background without notification from version 8 to 11

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-application

i'm developing an android app caller name announcer i want my app service run in background after i kill the app but it's working less than O version of android greather than O version it's working with notifications i wanna it not show notification in android 8 to 11 version

I am trying to solve the issue please help me someone

```
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, IncomingCallService::class.java)
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val incomingCallService = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_INCOMING_CALL, "Caller Name Announcer",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        val manager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(incomingCallService)


        IncomingCallService.startService(applicationContext, intent)
    }
    else{
        startService(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use if else condition

```kotlin
if (build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= build.VERSION_CODE.o) {
  // Your code
} else {
  // Your code
}
```